# Manually computing the euclidean norm of the difference between two MNIST images with PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, mnist

I've been playing around with the MNIST dataset and PyTorch and have loaded my dataset like so:

```
#Loading the MNIST training and test data:

train_data = datasets.MNIST(
    root = 'data',
    train = True,                         
    transform = ToTensor(), 
    download = True,            
)
test_data = datasets.MNIST(
    root = 'data', 
    train = False, 
    transform = ToTensor()
)
```

what's interesting to me is that I am thinking of these images as 28 by 28 matrices with each entry representing the shade of the pixel. So I wanted to compute the Euclidean distance between two images after flattening them, in particular, I defined the following function:

```
def wtrain(i,j):
   s = train_data.data[i]
   t = train_data.data[j]
   s = torch.flatten(s)
   t = torch.flatten(t)
   d = (s-t)/1000
   d = (torch.norm(d))**2
   return d
```

**What's weird is that wtrain[0,1] does not equal wtrain[1,0]?**

I was wondering if anyone could see why or offer an alternative way to compute this distance.

Comment: Do you have particular inputs and outputs to share?

Comment: Sure, I can. For w[0,1], I get  roughly 4.8 and for w[1,0] I get roughly 6.83. The point behind this is that d should be the same in both cases.

Comment: 0 and 1 are just indices into a data matrix.  We don't have that matrix for testing.